# Statically linking C++ libraries is failed

Tags: c, gcc, c++11, g++

I am interested in including C++ language in my c based program. I have two systems *(Host and Target)* which target system is limited, especially in memory. So, in my host machine, I have to statically link some libraries which will be needed by the program on target side. However, in my makefile I have been manipulating gcc patch (using a variety of gcc flags, during both compiling and linking steps).

Everything is ok until using C++ language;
For example, By including iostream header file in .cpp file, there exist an error on the target system showing that : "can not resolve symbol 'wctob' "

I must indicate my makefile as bellow:

```
in the compiling step: 

$(CXX) -O0 -I<Headers dir> $(LIBSC) -Wno-write-strings -Wno-narrowing -Wno-return-type -Wno-abi -Wno-unused-variable -DNDEBUG  -Wa, -c -fmessage-length=0 -I<Headers dir>  -march=4kec -EL -o "$@" "$<"


in the linking step: 

$(CXX) -lpthread -Wl,-Map,output.map $(MyFlags) $(LIBS) $(STRIP) -muclibc -march=4kec -EL -o 
"output.elf" $(OBJS) $(LIBS) $(MyFlags) -Wl,-rpath -Wl,<LIBDIR> -L<LIBDIR>
```

------some definitions

`MyFlags =  -lc -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc`;(such flags used in the linking step)

`LIBDIR  = is the address of needed libraries`

`LIBSC   = -nostdinc++` ;(such flags used in the compiling step)

`Headers dir` = is the address of needed both c and c++ header files included by the programmer.

`LIBS and OBJS` are also the list of needed libraries and objects.

Also, I added LIBDIR to ld.so.conf and LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but the problem is not solved far away. (My g++ version is 4.7.3.)

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell C++ compiler to use C naming and symbols. so :

```
extern "C" {

// your cpp codes

}
```